# Calendar arbitrage in implied vol grid with discrete and proportional dividends

Tags: implied-volatility, arbitrage, dividends

I have an implied vol **discrete** grid, obtained from market data.
To obtain prices from these implied vols, a dividend model with discrete and proportional dividends is used.

How can I verify if there are calendar arbitrages in this implied vol grid?

[This paper (Gatheral, Jacquier. Arbitrage free SVI volatility surfaces)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf) says, in Lemma 2.1 on page 3, that if dividends are **proportional only**, then verifying that the total variance is increasing is a necessary and sufficient condition of no-arbitrage.

Though, in my case dividends are not only proportional, there are also cash dividends.

On page 4 of the same paper, definition 2.2 (without proof) says that the increasing total variance is a sufficient condition of non-arbitrage, without specifying any assumption on dividends.

I want to know if I interpreted correctly this definition 2.2, i.e. if there are both cash and proportional dividends, then

- If I demonstrate that total variance is increasing, then I am sure that there is no arbitrage in the vol grid.
- If there are some points where total variance is not increasing, I am not sure that if there is or if there is not arbitrage on that point, i.e. the increasing total variance condition is sufficient for non-arbitrage, but not necessary.
- Mathematically: if dividends are both discrete with cash and proportional, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left[ \sigma^{2}(k, T)T \right] >0\Rightarrow \text{No-arbitrage}$

Are these 3 assertions correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great reference on discrete fixed/proportional dividends with local volatility. In your case you need to consider the pure stock process with the dividends removed and consider the conditions in section 3.2.

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1141877

There’s also a follow up paper to this one here

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2639318

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 2.1 on [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46528351_Arbitrage-free_smoothing_of_the_implied_volatility_surface), the calendar arbitrage condition is derived from portfolio of "a short position on short tenor, $T_1$, call and a long position on long tenor, $T_2$, call".

In the case of the cash dividend, the value of portfolio at time $t = T_1$ is equal to a put option minus the present value of the cash dividends between 2 tenors due to call-put parity.

Therefore, calendar arbitrage exists if $C(K_1,T_1) > e^{-\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \delta_tdt} C(K_2,T_2) + PV(Cash Dividends)$